# Replacement HVAC blower motor fails within 24 hours?

Tags: hvac, central-heating, heat-pump, carrier

My unit is a Carrier Infinity (FE4ANF003T00ABAA) with an ECM 3.0 blower motor.

To start, the thermostat reported a “Code 41 - Blower Motor Fault”. I ordered a refurbished motor + control module online and a surge protector (didn’t have one previously) and installed it. Ran it through the 5 minute heating diagnostic with no issues, but within 24hrs it had failed with a “Code 44 - Cannot Communicate with Blower” error.

I called up the company and they sent a new control module. Before installing the new control module (on their motor, not the original), I tested for signs of shorting with the multimeter, but resistance readings looked okay.

After attaching the module and reinstalling, it again ran fine through the 5 minute diagnostic, but within 24 hours failed again with Code 44.

I tested that the board is sending 12V to the motor controller and tested with and without the surge protector.

Anyone have suggestions on next steps? Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I suppose it's possible that your refurbished motor also had a problem but I think it's more likely there is some other cause for these issues.  I'd start with the basics, power and ground connections, loose connections inside the unit, etc.

Comment: Is there a vane switch or pressure switch that monitors the pressure? I have seen folks jump to the motor when it was a safety switch that was failing.

Answer (score 1):

There was an issue with the refurbished replacement motor/parts.

I purchased another replacement motor from a different retailer and it has been working without issue for about the past year.